# Is it possible to have Colorbox overlay open at the top of the page but not allow scrolling up?

Tags: javascript, overlay, colorbox

As the title says, I am trying to implement a colorbox overlay whereby the overlay is positioned at the top, and the user cannot scroll up, hence showing the blackened areas if you are opening the overlay from the middle of a long page. This issue is particular annoying on mobile devices. Actually as an extension to this 'wish', it would be equally great if we could only scroll until the end of the overlay, and not past it.

The first method to solve this would probably be

**The Fixed position, top: 0 method**

Problem is this assumes your overlay is always within the window size. If your overlay is taller than the window size and requires scrolling to view it in its entirety, you can't scroll the overlay with the fixed positioning

The ugly solution would be to do the above, keep the overlay in a conservative height and allow the scrolling parameter in colorbox. This however is unideal as it shows ugly scrollbars on certain browsers.

So I'm hoping if anyone knows of a way to prevent scrolling up perhaps, when the overlay is open? For preventing scrolling down past the overlay, I'm hoping for some javascript sages enlightenment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can use JavaScript to add overflow to the BG

Try this code:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
            $('html').css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
        }).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
            $('html').css({ overflow: '' });
        });
        });
```

I found this here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-background-scrolling-when-colorbox-layer-is-active?replies=3

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try set the body's css property overflow:hidden, e.g. in jQuery

```
$('body').css({overflow:'hidden'})
```

Comment: Yeah I did that, but it still comes down to everything being unscrollable, which is half of what I want, but if my overlay extends past the current window size, I'm screwed. Also, this method doesn't seem to work on mobile.